# Replace div background url with img src on jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a menu, each item of which contains a div with a background url. It looks like this:

```
<div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/1.jpg)"></div>
</div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/2.jpg)"></div>
</div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/3.jpg)"></div>
</div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/4.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

I try it like this:

```
jQuery (function($) {
    
    $('.iksm-terms-tree--children .iksm-term__image-container').html('<img>');
    
    $('.iksm-terms-tree--children .iksm-term__image-container').each(function() {
        var url = $('.iksm-term__image').css('background-image');
        url = url.replace(/url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','/url');
        $('.iksm-term__image').css('background-image', 'none');
    });
    
    
});
```

But instead of the path to the image, I get just a "url":

```
<div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="/url"></div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="/url"></div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="/url"></div>
<div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="/url"></div>
```

I would be grateful for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your line of code: `$('.iksm-terms-tree--children .iksm-term__image-container').html('<img>');` is you overwrite all lines inside each `iksm-term__image-container`, so `$('.iksm-term__image')` dont exist after that . To avoid that, trap the url before overwritting the html div:

```js
$(function($) {

  $('.iksm-terms-tree--children .iksm-term__image-container').each(function() {
  
    //trap the background property
    var url = $(this).find(".iksm-term__image").css('background-image');
    //keep only url between parenthesis
    url = url.replace(/url\(([^\)]+)\)/, '$1');
    //replace line by tag `img` with the right url directly
    $(this).html(`<img src=${url}>`);

    //$(this).find('img').attr('src', url);
    //$('.iksm-term__image').css('background-image', 'none');
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="iksm-terms-tree--children">
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/1.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/2.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/3.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container">
    <div class="iksm-term__image" style="background-image: url(https://example.com/4.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

new html code:

```
<div class="iksm-terms-tree--children">
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="https://example.com/1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="https://example.com/2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="https://example.com/3.jpg"></div>
  <div class="iksm-term__image-container"><img src="https://example.com/4.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes got it! That's the actual problem @sergey-pervushin

Comment: Right), missed it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You just did a minor mistake I think. You provide a variable as a value(String). e.g `('/url')`

**Solution:**

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src',url);
```

or if you require extra `/` in that case,

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src','/'+url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I tried this and then it returns ```<img src="none">```

Comment: Okay, so in this case the issue is the `url` variable not having the data. Have you check whether you get valid url in `url` variable by alert or something else?

Comment: I must admit, I do not know how to check it(

Comment: Yeah sure, simply put `alert(url);` before `$(this).find('img').attr('src','/url');`. And then you get alert dialog in browser with the value.

Comment: You should also write `alert(url);` above the `url = url.replace(/url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');` , for double check. (Value before replace the url)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint, it returns "none". So something is wrong in the regular expression?

Comment: I think you can't able to get the value from `$('.iksm-term__image').css('background-image');` It should return none. Have you checked it? Because regular expression can return the 'none'. The regular expression is right I guess.